# Enable Fips for MQ-messaging no effect

Tags: spring, ssl, ibm-mq, fips

I try to use `SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` with FIPS enabled to connect to an IBM MQ 7.5.0.5.

My problem is that I receive an error because the ciphersuites don't match.
In my Queuemanager I see, that the suite, used by my client is still TRIPLE_DES_SHA_US as if FIPS is still disabled. But in my springframework-bean I'm using:

```
<prop key="javax.net.ssl.sslFipsRequired">true</prop>
```

And in my `MQQueueConnectionFactory`-bean I'm using:

```
<property name="SSLFipsRequired" value="true" />
```

Is there another possible place where I have to add the fips-required property?

**Edit:**

The JMS-Report says:

```
 JVM does not contain a FIPS compliant JSSE
```

So I think the problem could be the jsse.

Comment: Isn't `javax.net.ssl.sslFipsRequired` needed as a environment/system property?

Comment: If it exists at all it would be a system property.

Comment: Are you specifying the SSLCipherSuite through property or through JNDI bindings?

Comment: @Umapathy through properties. But the error-logs say, that my  JVM does not contain a FIPS compliant JSSE

Comment: It seems to me that FIPS mode needs to be "enabled" in the JVM: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/FIPS.html

Comment: I've seen that. But how do I know which Provider I have to use?